# How can I use webpack to build a package that I can use in another react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack

My organization has a custom build datatable that is built with React, compiled and used in several other applications. One of those other applications is itself a React app. We recently updated our larger react app so that we're using the latest builds on several npm packages, and the datatable build stopped working within react. I decided to try building the datatable in webpack the same way to get them working again, but I can't seem to produce a file that builds the datatable react into something I can import as a local package.

Here's the webpack.config.js I'm using to build the datatable. Any advice would be very welcome.

```
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = [
    {
        entry: './src/react/datatable/datatable-component.jsx',
        externals: [nodeExternals()],
        name: 'datatable-react',
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/assets/js/datatable'),
            filename: 'datatable.js',
            chunkFilename: '[id].js',
            publicPath: ''
        },
        mode: 'production',
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/
                }
            ]
        }
    },
];
```

Comment: How are you trying to "import as a local package"?

Comment: Compile using webpack into a .js file, then copy the file into the other project and do
`import Datatable from '../localfile/datatable.js';`